# CheckBox - Show a tick mark on store list when work is done for that store

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a first screen where I have the option to start the activity and checkbox.

Now, when you click on start activity it will take you to another page and that page contains a button complete activity. When you press on complete activity, automatically, the screen pops up and the checkbox is marked.

```
Checkbox(
  value: isChecked,
  onChanged: (value) {
    toggleCheckbox(value);
  },
  activeColor: Colors.green,
  checkColor: Colors.white,
  tristate: false,
),
```

Comment: I don't see a question being asked here. I see a statement about what your first screen does.

Comment: Use state management (For example: BloC, Redux or other state managements)